# Possible Attack autoshell.txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this error reported to me recently from my Rails app.

> mycontroller#update (ArgumentError) "invalid %-encoding (<%MYTEST)
>
> An ArgumentError occurred in mycontroller#update:
>
> invalid %-encoding (<%MYTEST)

These are the parameters that were passed.

> Parameters : {"controller"=>"mycontroller", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"autoshell", "format"=>"txt"}

Should I be worried? I recently upgraded to Rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1.3. What is autoshell.txt?

Comment: it happens in a production environment? where is the `<%MYTEST` string coming from?

Comment: It is in my production environment. It happened twice from an ip address originating in Kansas City according to iplocation.net. I don't know where the <%MYTEST string is coming from. It isn't in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be somebody scanning for websites vulnerable to JCE Joomla Extension Auto Shell Upload Exploit. Really nothing to worry about.

Comment: Nothing to worry about... unless he was running an exploitable version of joomla? :)

Answer (score 3):

I've been seeing this error in our logs as well.  I'm not concerned about it personally, but if it becomes annoying you can add this to your routes.rb file:

> put '/autoshell', to: proc { [404, {}, ['']] }

That will return an empty 404 response.

Comment: This line needs to be above any catchall routes or any other routes that could catch this request.

Comment: @EricCoulthard chasing things like this individually is rather futile; there are thousands of these kinds of automated exploit attempts that you'll get hit with; just be aware that this isn't going to fix much.